# writing 2 data frames in parallel in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example 
I am doing a lot of calculations
and I am finally down to
3 dataframes.

for example:

```
val mainQ = spark.sql("select * from employee")
mainQ.createOrReplaceTempView("mainQ")
val mainQ1 = spark.sql("select state,count(1) from mainQ group by state")
val mainQ2 = spark.sql("select dept_id,sum(salary) from mainQ group by dept_id")
val mainQ3 = spark.sql("select  dept_id,state , sum(salary) from mainQ     group by dept_id,state")
//Basically I want to write below writes in parallel. I could put into 
//Different files. But that is not what I am looking at. Once all         computation is done. I want to write the data in parallel.
mainQ1.write.mode("overwrite").save("/user/h/mainQ1.txt")
mainQ2.write.mode("overwrite").save("/user/h/mainQ2.txt")
mainQ3.write.mode("overwrite").save("/user/h/mainQ3.txt")
```

Comment: dataframes are already working in parallel when you have spark cluster. Now if you still want two dataframes to work together, then I would suggest you to implement thread concept.

Answer (score 3):

Normally there is no benefit using multi-threading in the driver code, but sometimes it can increase performance. I had some situations where launching parallel spark jobs increased performance drastically, namely when the individual jobs do not utilize the cluster resources well (e.g. due to data skew, too few partitions etc). In your case you can do:

```
ParSeq(
  (mainQ1,"/user/h/mainQ1.txt"),
  (mainQ2,"/user/h/mainQ2.txt"),
  (mainQ3,"/user/h/mainQ3.txt")
).foreach{case (df,filename) => 
  df.write.mode("overwrite").save(filename)
}
```

Comment: I thought any for statement - to go to the next (for ex 2nd) iteration. The 1st iteration should be done. So in that sense wouldn't it still be running in sequential mode? I will give it a try.

Comment: I tested and could see that they are all launched at same time. But it took additional time rather than sequential. May be due to the fact that spark might need more memory? So in my case it was a little slower to run in parallel vs sequential